# What's wrong with the resolution of rasters?

Tags: qgis, raster

I have two world area rasters. The metadata showed as follows:

file1:

```
Driver
GDAL provider
ENVI
ENVI .hdr Labelled
Dataset Description
D:/temp/2000npp/MOD17A3_Science_NPP_2000.tif
Band 1
Dimensions
X: 4500 Y: 1750 Bands: 1
X : 2250,Y 875
X : 1125,Y 438
X : 563,Y 219
X : 282,Y 110
Origin
-180,80
Pixel Size
0.08,-0.08
No Data Value
*NoDataValue not set* 
Data Type
UInt16 - Sixteen bit unsigned integer 
Pyramid overviews
Layer Spatial Reference System
+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
Layer Extent (layer original source projection)
-180.0000000000000000,-60.0000472867500037 : 180.0001215945000013,80.0000000000000000
Band
Band 1
Band No
1
No Stats
No stats collected yet
```

file2:

```
Driver
GDAL provider
GTiff
GeoTIFF
Dataset Description
D:/temp/2000npp/2000.tif
AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Band 1
STATISTICS_COVARIANCES=559.9966665827818
STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=164.06666564941
STATISTICS_MEAN=10.482447155964
STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
STATISTICS_SKIPFACTORX=1
STATISTICS_SKIPFACTORY=1
STATISTICS_STDDEV=23.664248701
Dimensions
X: 4500 Y: 2250 Bands: 1
X : 2250,Y 1125
X : 1125,Y 563
X : 563,Y 282
X : 282,Y 141
Origin
-180,90
Pixel Size
0.08,-0.08
No Data Value
-3.40282e+38 
Data Type
Float32 - Thirty two bit floating point 
Pyramid overviews
Layer Spatial Reference System
+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
Layer Extent (layer original source projection)
-180.0000000000000000,-89.9999959766864777 :  179.9999919533729553,90.0000000000000000
Band
Band 1
Band No
1
No Stats
No stats collected yet
```

The rows number of file1 is 1750 while file2 is 2250 while both cols number is 4500. And the extent area looks like 80°N to 60°S on Geography showed in the map. But the file2  looks like stretched. I'm puzzle that: 
If with pixel size 0.08° and 2250 rows, the map should contain artic pole area and antiartic( 90°N to 90°S ,for 2250*0.08=180). I think the file1 is right (1750*0.08=140 ,from 80°N to 60°S). What's wrong with file2? How to adjust it?

file1 showed in QGIS:
[image]

file2 showed in QGIS:
[image]

raster lay overlap will show clearly:
[image]

Comment: Does file2 have anything else than nodata outside the -80 - +80 range? Are the coordinates of Cap Horn correct?

Comment: @user30184，there is no other rows out -80 ,the Cap Horn is nearly in the edge of the map.(the bankground color is blank in file2)

Comment: And what is the latitude of Cap Horn if you measure it from file2?

Comment: @user30184 Cap Horn is -85° . So the coordination of file2 rasters is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Only the one who created the image "file2" can know what happened for the georeferencing. If the image extents are unchanged you can correct the georeferencing with gdal_translate http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html and -a_ullr

> **-a_ullr** ulx uly lrx lry:
>
> Assign/override the georeferenced bounds of the output file. This assigns georeferenced bounds to the output file, ignoring what would
>   have been derived from the source file. So this does not cause
>   reprojection to the specified SRS.

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -a_ullr -180 80 180 -60 D:/temp/2000npp/2000.tif D:/temp/2000npp/2000_fixed.tif
```